# converting timestamp to datetime in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a timestamp which is coming from a remote Linux box. This is the timestamp 1356354496.
When I am using the fromtimestamp function I am getting a different output then what it should be.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
print(time.ctime(int("1356354496")))
cwStartTimeDisplay=datetime.fromtimestamp(int("1356354496")).strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
print(cwStartTimeDisplay)
```

Output

Mon Dec 24 05:08:16 2012
Mon Dec 24 05:08:16 2012

Whereas I should be getting 12/24/2012 6:38:16 PM. I am a beginner and don't really know if tz parameter is the answer to this. Can anybody help please?

Comment: likely a tz issue. what are the local timezones of the two machines? How do you obtain the timestamp on the remote machine? using `time.time()`?

Comment: both are IST's. I am getting the timestamp from pywbem

Answer (score 3):

Your timestamp seems to be `UTC`, so if you need id represented in `IST`, you need to convert it.

The recommended library to work with timezone data in python is [`pytz`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz)

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
ist = pytz.timezone("Asia/Kolkata")

utcdate = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1356354496))
print("UTC:", utcdate)
istdate = ist.normalize(utcdate)
print("IST:", istdate)

# or shorter:
date = datetime.fromtimestamp(1356354496, ist)
print("IST:", date)
```

output:

```
UTC: 2012-12-24 13:08:16+00:00
IST: 2012-12-24 18:38:16+05:30
IST: 2012-12-24 18:38:16+05:30
```

Comment: Thanks Mata!!
There was a problem with my machine. When I tested the same sample code and the code implemented in the project on another machine it worked fine. :)